# Is this reclaimed wood repairable?

Tags: wood-repair, reclaimed-wood

There is a large chunk missing from this dining table and I'm worried it is unrepairable. If it can't be repaired, could you explain why? [image]

Comment: Do you have the missing piece?  Also some more photos for context would help.

Comment: Unfortunately this is for a client of mine and this was damaged during delivery so there isn't a missing piece and this is the only picture of damage.

Comment: Almost any damage of this kind is repairable, so if that's basically all you want to know the answer is yes. Obviously cost may be a factor in whether it's considered worth it, both with a DIY repair and if getting a pro to do it. Repair work can be costly and can even exceed the value of a piece of furniture unfortunately, frequently making repairs not viable in a purely monetary sense.

Comment: Could someone explain why it shouldn't be repaired?

Answer (score 1):

It should and could be repaired.

One idea I had was to lightly pencil in a line square with the top at the same distance on each side from the corner. Use a couple of straight edges to find the corner that is out in space.

Now, I can think of several fixes but these two are similar with different effect:

Use a handsaw to carefully cut across the corner on both lines you drew. Then find a species of wood that, after test staining and finishing samples, would blend in. Use wood glue to adhere a piece ever so slightly oversized that will bridge the lost corner. Finish per your test piece.

Is that a ribbon of black inlay in the top? If so you might try this:
Using similar layout lines as before, you could fill the corner with black epoxy or a contrasting wood piece stained black. Of course you would want to do all four corners for esthetics.

As for the very top of the table, I might start by sanding a new radius and try to match the finish.